# List/Conditional Comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list, scikit-learn, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I was wondering how to make the following into a comprehension:

```
for g in a:
    for f in g[::3]:
        if f == clf.best_params_:
            print g
```

I tried this:

```
p = [[print g for g in a] if f==clf.best_params for f in [g[::3] for g in a]]
p
```

but got an error at `for f in`

Would love some help! Thanks!

Comment: Generally, loops with side-effects (like printing) don't lend themselves to being made into comprehensions ...

Comment: You do realize that print returns `None`?

Comment: @leaf -- It looks like OP is on python2.x where `print` is a statement (barring `__future__` imports of course).

Comment: @mgilson Shoot! I always miss that.

Comment: Comprehension is a way to create a list, not simply to do things repeatedly, for which the for loop is already Pythonic =)

Comment: List comprehensions are for making lists. If your goal is a side effect (like printing) then use a regular loop. Also since you are using Python 2, `print` is a statement and therefore cannot be used in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to translate those loops would be

```
[print g for g in a for f in g[::3] if f == clf.best_params_]
```

However, in Python 2 `print g` is a statement, and that's why you get a SyntaxError. The Python 3 counterpart (i.e. with `print(g)`) would work, but note that a list comprehension here is completely useless. A list comprehension is useful when you have to gather values into a list - here it just hampers the readability.

Regarding the SyntaxError, it's not the primary issue here. Note that you can use

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

and then use the `print()` function in your list comprehension as you would in Python 3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The clarity was very helpful and it was nice to hear the print SyntaxError articulated. My intention was to store a list, not print, but I accidentally left the print statement in when checking if the loop works.

Comment: @FlowNuwen Glad I could be of help. If your intention is to store a list, then what I wrote initially is how you write the list comprehension: all the for loops are one after the other and the innermost if statement is at the end. Note that either you have one if statement or you have none. You cannot have multiple if statements in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've confused the construct: it's a **list** comprehension, not a macro of some sort.

You don't get this sort of side effect; the purpose of a list comprehension is to construct a list.

Comment: You *do* get the side effects though. The list is then full of useless values. On the other hand, I agree with you that a list comprehension is totally misused here.

Comment: You can get side effects in list comprehensions eg. mutating the list but it is very bad practice. This example tries to use a `print` `statement` which isn't even correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

**Rule 1** - Keep the order of the `for` and `if` parts the same. The only part that changes order is the last part, `print g`: that moves to the front.

```
[print g for g in a for f in g[::3] if f == clf.best_params_]
```

**Rule 2** - List comprehensions should not *do* anything. Instead of *printing* `g`, have `g` be the value that is accumulated.

```
[g for g in a for f in g[::3] if f == clf.best_params_]
```

If your entire goal was simply to print things, stick with the original loops; a list comprehension wouldn't add any value.

---

If we take another look at your original nested loops, there may be a better way to write them. Is your goal to find all the items `g` that have `clf.best_params_` in one of the matching positions? If so, I recommend replacing the inner loop with a single `if any` statement.

```
for g in a:
    if any(f == clf.best_params_ for f in g[::3]):
        print g
```

To me, this reads better. The logic is clearer. It will only print any one value of `g` once, instead of multiple times if `clf.best_params_` is present more than once.

If that is an improvement, then you could convert that version to a list comprehension like so:

```
[g for g in a if any(f == clf.best_params_ for f in g[::3])]
```

Comment: can I ask the source for these rules

Comment: The first one is simply how the conversion works. The second isn't a "rule" so much as a best practice. I treat it like a rule: I never write list comprehensions that have side effects.

Comment: Thank you! My intention was not to print, but I just put it in to check it was working originally.